# Ubuntu 21.04 stuck on black screen with blinking cursor at boot

Tags: boot, drivers, amdgpu, 21.04

Installed Ubuntu 21.04 on an Asus Rog Scar Strix 2021 laptop (AMD iGPU and Nvidia dGPU), successfully booted in, installed nvidia-driver-460 (proprietary, tested) drivers using additional drivers tab under the Software & Updates settings GUI.

Rebooted, and now i get stuck at a black screen with a blinking cursor in the top left indefinitely.
I can boot in only after `Ctrl` +`Alt` + `F2`, Logging into a session via command line, logging out, then `Ctrl` + `D` until the GUI login shows up then i can resume using ubuntu like normal.

There is a quick flash of text before the GUI login  screen shows up, displaying two lines of error:

`[FAILED] Failed to start Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight" acpi_video0`

`[FAILED] Failed to start Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight" amdgpu_b10`

`uname -a` produces `Linux Strix 5.11.0-16-generic #17-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 14 20:12:43 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

How Can i remedy this so i am showed the normal GUI login when i start up ?

I do not have `lightdm` installed, is this something I need ?

Is this related to Ubuntu 21.04 using Wayland ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to report it as a bug. https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/report-ubuntu-bug.html.en

Comment: do you also encounter the issue, that every button is a power off button under linux?

Comment: @Pascalius thats an issue i had using ubuntu 20.04. There was a work around here  https://liamfrappell.medium.com/fixing-black-screen-and-keyboard-shutdown-issues-on-an-asus-rog-strix-scar-2021-laptop-in-ubuntu-20-9ce964bf34d0
There are a number of hoops to jump through, most of which are solved by just using 21.04 (Kernel change, adding AMD specific binaries, mismatch gcc version that was used to build the kernel, Nvidia driver issues)

Answer (score 0):

Okay after playing around i think i fixed it.
Steps:

1. Via terminal run `nvidia-settings`
2. Click on `PRIME Profiles` on the left, and select `NVIDIA On-Demand`
3. Reboot

In my case it led to me seeing the normal Ubuntu GUI 21.04 login screen, and nvidia proprietary drivers are still installed and are able to be used.

Hopefully this works for you as well !

Comment: The result of "on-Demand" is probably defaulting to the iGPU. The symptoms you describe are very likely related with Secure Boot. If enabled it prevents the Nvidia proprietary drivers from loading, it doesn't affect the AMD open-source ones for AMD. Wayland is still not compatible with Nvidia drivers. You have to make your decision based on that and adjust accordingly - Secure Boot OFF and X.org - if you ever want to use the dGPU.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same behavior with my Razer Blade Laptop but I'm not able to run the nvidia-settings command to change the On-Demand.

I tried the Ctrl+D and logging in / out via the cmd line but I'm not able to get to a GUI to login.